# rename files in zip folder using zipmodule

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can rename a file called "logo.png" in my zip folder under ("fw/resources/logo.png") to ("fw/resources/logo.png.bak"), using python's zip module.

Comment: You can't with the built in `zipfile` module.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by rocksportrocker, you cannot rename/remove a file from a zipfile archive. You would have iterate over the files in the zipfile and selectively add the files you want. So to remove a certain directory from the zipfile, you would not copy them to the new zipfile. That would be something like this:

```
source = ZipFile('source.zip', 'r')
target = ZipFile('target.zip', 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
for file in source.filelist:
    if not file.filename.startswith('directory-to-remove/'):
        target.writestr(file.filename, source.read(file.filename))
target.close()
source.close()
```

As this would read all the files into memory, it would not be an ideal solution for large archives. For small archives this works as advertised.

Comment: Does it really load the whole file in memory?

Answer (score 4):

I think that is not possible: the zipfile modules has no methods for that, and as mentioned in [Renaming a File/Folder inside a Zip File in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847892/renaming-a-file-folder-inside-a-zip-file-in-java) the internal structure of zip files is in the way. So you have to do unzip, rename, zip.

Update: Just found
[Delete file from zipfile with the ZipFile Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513788/delete-file-from-zipfile-with-the-zipfile-module) which should help you.

Comment: deletion can be done with os.rmdir of shutil.rmtree, but if you only want to rename a folder, us can use shutil.move

Comment: actually, how would i delete a file in the zip folder?