# How can I rename a file inside a zip archive with python?

Tags: python, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rename files in zip folder using zipmodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428318/rename-files-in-zip-folder-using-zipmodule)

I am manipulating a zip archive with multiple files. I am retrieving the namelist of files that are included in the zip and What I would like to achieve is to rename some of the files according to my conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The only operations you can perform on an unzipped archive are read-only ones; you can't edit the content of anything inside a zip file.