# Renaming files inside a zip file

Tags: python, batch-file, zip, file-rename, batch-rename

I am trying to write a python script to rename files (containing a predefined string with another predefined string).
How do I rename files and folders in a zip file, without extracting the zip file (as it could be very large)?

```
import os
import zipfile
old_name="ABCD"
new_name="XYZ"

for d,s,files in os.walk(path):
 for f in files:
   if f.startswith(old_name) and f.endswith('.zip'):
     with zipfile.ZipFile(f,'a') as zf:
       for files_inside_zip in zf.namelist():
        if files_inside_zip.startswith(old_name):
          ## Now I need to rename only this particular file
          ## some files are larger than 1 GB
          ## and contains 1000+ files
          ## so extracting all doest seems to be a good idea

     zf.close
```

Comment: Please show us some code, what you already did and what error you are getting. SO is not a place where you drop your request and others solve it for your.

Comment: Duplicate of [rename files in zip folder using zipmodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428318/rename-files-in-zip-folder-using-zipmodule)

Comment: @codedge Updated the code I am trying to execute

Answer (score -1):

There is no way of modifying a zipped archive without extracting it, in Python. One way I can think of that **may** solve your problem, assuming that you are on linux, is to execute a bash script in Python, that uses vim to transparently edit the archive:

Sources:
Modifying zip file in python: [overwriting file in ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653768/overwriting-file-in-ziparchive)
Executing bash script from python: [Running bash script from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745648/running-bash-script-from-within-python)
Edit zip archive with vim: https://superuser.com/questions/647674/is-there-a-way-to-edit-files-inside-of-a-zip-file-without-explicitly-extracting